# How to rename top level site URL in SharePoint Server?

Tags: my-site, administration

How can I rename the top level site URL website name in SharePoint server 2010?

```
moss10/my/personal/    PS    /SitePages/Home.aspx
```

Website name: `PS`

How to Change `PS` to `PSSOFT`?

Please Explain

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Additional care needs to be given for personal sites since there is a pointer to it in the User Profile.  If you make a change, you will need to change the user profile as well.  Typically I do not recommend changing the site's URL for a person, even when their name changes since this is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

Goto:

Site Settings -> Title, description, and icon

change the Title and URL

Comment: In Site Settings only changing Title and Description But not changed the Site Url

Comment: Is 'PS' the managed path to the top level site collection? If so I don't think it is possible to change

Comment: yes, If possible how it so please tell me

Answer (score 0):

My/Personal/ sounds like the managed path.  You can try to backup and restore the site to a new location.  [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/21/sharepoint-2010-granular-backup-restore-part-1.aspx) gives step by step instructions on how to backup and restore a site collection or subsite (export / import).